# Targeting specific element ID that is passed from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am currently listing 10 items per page , and problem is that when this function is called it will only target 1st (latest) element and do nothing on rest of them.
My question is :
How would i target each individual 
`<span id="report-text"></span>` 
with `<i id="report"></i>` element that belong to same unique-id `<div id="$dbstuff></div>` given by PHP.

This is my Jquery code to target element

```
$('#report').hover(function(){
    $('#report-text').show();
},function(){
$('#report-text').hide();
});
```

HTML code is following :

```
<div class="vote_wrap" id="<?php echo $row->id;?>">
<span id="report-text">Report Inappropriate Content</span>
<i class="fa fa-exclamation" id="report"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: ids are unique; use a class

Comment: if there were another like me, this place would be absolute *mayhem* ;-)

Comment: Did that , but turns out its even worse , `.show()` is displacing elements all over page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by achieving right selectors .. use class as suggestions in comments ..

Do as below-

**JS**

```
 $('.report').hover(function(){
        $(this).prev('.report-text').show();
    },function(){
    $(this).prev('.report-text').hide();
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="vote_wrap" id="<?php echo $row->id;?>">
<span class="report-text">Report Inappropriate Content</span>
<i class="fa fa-exclamation" class="report"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you .. happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

> Each id value must be used only once within a document. If more than one element has been assigned the same ID, **queries that use that ID will only select the first matched element in the DOM.**

[Source](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

Change your `ID`'s to `Class`

Comment: That works , but not as intended what i get is every element showing and it is displacing every other element sending page in utter chaos.